# Rcpp: calling c++ function in R without exporting c++ function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to make a package with Rcpp. I have all of my `C++` functions in a single `.cpp` file as follows:

```
double meanvec(NumericVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  double tot = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tot += x[i];
  }
  tot /= n;
  return tot;
}

double inprod(NumericVector u, NumericVector v) {
  int m = u.size();
  double val = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    val += u[i] * v[i];
  }
  return val;
}

NumericVector lincoef(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  int n = x.size();
  double xm = meanvec(x);
  double ym = meanvec(y);
  NumericVector xa(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    xa[i] = x[i] - xm;
  }
  NumericVector ya(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ya[i] = y[i] - ym;
  }
  double b1 = inprod(xa, ya) / inprod(xa, xa);
  double b0 = ym - (b1 * xm);
  NumericVector beta = NumericVector::create(b0, b1);
  return beta;
}
```

Basically, the last function takes two vectors as input and outputs a single vector. I would like to call this function into a separate `.R` file where I am trying to write another function. Something like this:

```
#' Title
#'
#' @param x Numeric vector.
#' @param y Numeric vector.
#'
#' @return
#' @export
linfit338 = function(x, y){
  beta = .Call(`_pkg338_lincoef`, x, y)
  fmod = function(x){
    beta[1] + beta[2]*x
  }
  flist = list(beta, fmod)
  return(flist)
}
```

Here the output is a list, where the first element is a vector from the `C++` function being called and the second element is the created function. When I try to install and restart, I get this error message:

```
RcppExports.o:RcppExports.cpp:(.rdata+0x790): undefined reference to `_pkg338_lincoef'
```

My guess is that is has something to do with exporting the function. When I add `// [[Rcpp::export]]` above the `lincoef` function in the `C++` file, I don't get any error message, and my final `R` function works. However, my whole goal is that I do not want the `lincoef` function exported at all.

Any way to fix this? I would also be open to suggestions as to how I can improve organizing these files, as this is my first experience building a package with `Rcpp`.

Comment: Please *please* *PLEASE* at least _glance_ at the fairly recent [Rcpp-introduction](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) vignette, and possibly also the [Rcpp Attributes](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) one.  And/or consider starting from a 'create a package with Rcpp' helper such as the one in RStudio or of course our `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` function written for *exactly* this purpose.

Comment: "I do not want the lincoef function exported at all" is saying I do not want to call it from R.  You can still control via `NAMESPACE` what your package exports.

Comment: In addition to what @DirkEddelbuettel has said, a look at Writing R Extensions would be a worthwhile investment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming and Hiding an Exported Rcpp function in an R Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039132/renaming-and-hiding-an-exported-rcpp-function-in-an-r-package)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're probably mixing up the concept of exporting C++ code to be used in R (via `// [[Rcpp::export]]`), which is entirely different to exporting R functions from your package, i.e. making those functions available to end-users of your package.

To make your Rcpp functions callable from within R at all, you *need* to `// [[Rcpp::export]]` them. If you don't do this, none of your C++ code will be available from within your R package.

It sounds like what you would like to do is to use the Rcpp-exported functions within your package but to hide them from end-users. This is a common use case for Rcpp, as it allows you to have an R function that acts as an end-user interface to your C++ code, while leaving you free to alter the C++ implementation in future developments without the risk of breaking existing users' code.

*Any* function you have created within your package, be it an R function or an Rcpp-exported function, has to actively be *exported* from your package to make it available to end-users. This is a different concept from `// [[Rcpp::export]]`, which is needed to access C++ functions from within your package's R code.

Any R functions will only be exported from your R package if you specify them in the `NAMESPACE` file in your project's root directory. Thus to export `myfunction()` you need to have a line that says `export(myfunction)` in the NAMESPACE file. You are using roxygen2, which will generate this line automatically as long as you write `@export` in the roxygen skeleton. An alternative to using roxygen's exporting system is to specify an `exportPattern` in the `NAMESPACE` file that uses regex to export only functions whose names match a certain pattern.

My usual workflow is to prefix any Rcpp-exported functions with a period by writing my C++ functions like this:

```
// [[Rcpp::export(.MyCppFunction)]]
int BoringFunction() { return 0; }
```

I can now call the C++ function from R like this:

```
MyRFunction <- function()
{
  result <- .MyCppFunction()
  return(result)
}
```

The first line in my `NAMESPACE` file looks like this:

```
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

Which means that any R function in my package starting with a letter will be exported. Since all the functions I `Rcpp::export` start with a period, I can use them internally within the R package but they won't be exported to end-users.

In other words, end-users of the package can call `MyRFunction()` but would get an error if they tried to call `.MyCppFunction`

Comment: Nice answer. One trick to add is that `// [[Rcpp::export(.linCoef)]]` would be exported _from C++_ to an _R function_ following the 'if it starts with a dot it is "hidden" as an R function' convention which would appear to be the desire here.  Then there is no need to change the regexp in `NAMESPACE` as dot-starting names to not match 'starts with alphanumerical character'.